# Exception "The specified entity is not contained in this EntitySet." but Entity is contained

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have an exception "`The specified entity is not contained in this EntitySet.`" . But when I look my dataSource, is see my entity in there.

Here is the code :

```
     Class1 item = (Class1)dg.SelectedItem;

     if (item!= null)
     {
         Class2 item2= new Class2();
         item2.Att1= item.Att1;
         item2.Att2= item.Att2;
         item2.Att3= item.Att3;
         MyDataSource.DataView.Remove(item2);

     }
```

I want to delete object of my DataSource, which have attributes of the selected item in my datagrid.

When I watch on the DataSource, my item2 appears, so why can't I delete it from the DataSource? Same class, same attribute. I don't understand.

I found this, and it works well :

```
if (item!= null)
    {
    Class2 myPiece = MyDataSource.DataView.OfType<Class2>().Where(OrEs => OrEs.Att1 == item.Att1).FirstOrDefault() ;

    MyDataSource.dataView.Remove(myPiece);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to delete the same item, you are creating a new item which is giving issue.

Should be something like this

```
Class1 item = (Class1)dg.SelectedItem;

     if (item!= null)
     {
         MyDataSource.DataView.Remove(item );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Item2 is not part of your datasource.

Two objects of same type and attributes do not necessarily mean they are same, by same they should be on the same memory location.

You need to find the item that matches the same attributes in your datasoure and then delete that.

Comment: Well, in fact, the grid contains Object Class2, but the select in on a object Class1. But i found something : Class2 myPiece = MyDataSource.DataView.OfType<Class2>().Where(OrEs => OrEs.Att1 == item.Att1).FirstOrDefault() ; And it works.

Comment: The Class 2  item2 you created was a different object alltogether than the one you had in your datasource. The main idea was to find the item in the datasource which you did with your LinQ expression.